# button didn't trigger modal when using ui-routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create angular modal wizard using ui-routing. Inside my modal window I got two nested views which should be responsible for navigation inside the modal window by ui-sref directive. Although i added 'ui.bootstrap' and 'ui.router' modules in my app declaration, when I click button which should open enitre modal on console appears error:

"TransitionRejection(type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal".

app.js:

```
/* definition of angularJS application and include modules*/
var app = angular.module('accTrader', [
    'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'LocalStorageModule', 'duScroll', 'ngTouch'
]);

// routing config
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');


        $stateProvider        
        .state("home", {
            url: "/",
            template: '<button class="btn btn-default" ui-sref="modal"> Modal</button>',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
         })
        .state("aboutus", {
            url: "/aboutus",
            templateUrl: "app/views/aboutus.html" 
         })

        .state("category", {
            url: "/category/gameid/:gameid",
            controller: 'CategoryCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/category.html'
        }) 
        .state('modal', { // MODAL
            parent: 'home',
            url: '/modal',
            onEnter: ['$modal', '$state', function($modal, $state) {
                console.log('Open modal');
                $modal.open({
                template: '<button class="btn btn-danger" ui-sref="signin"> sign-in </button> <button ui-sref="signout" class="btn btn-success"> sign-out </button> <div ui-view="modal"></div>',
                backdrop: false,
                windowClass: 'right fade'
            }).result.finally(function() {
              $state.go('list');
          });
        }]
      })
      .state('signin', {
        url: '/signin',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<p>sign-in</p>'
            }
          }
      })
      .state('signout', {
        url: '/signout',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<p>sign-out</p>'
            }
          }
      })
}); // END ROUTING CONFIG
```

main part of index.html:

```
...
 <body ng-cloak id="top" ng-controller="ExternalCtrl">    
    <div ui-view></div>
    <a href="#top" du-smooth-scroll="">
        <div id="backToTop" class="bottomMenu hide"></div>
    </a>
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of UI Bootstrap. For some time now it has been [`$uibModal`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) not `$modal`.

It was updated in version 1.1.0 commit [8c7b9e4](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/8c7b9e4).

If you are using a 1.1.0 onwards then you should be injecting `$uibModal` not `$modal`.

Comment: Version: 2.3.1 - 2016-12-10

Comment: Then it should be `$uibModal` not `$modal`. Here is the 2.3.1 documentation for how to use the ui bootstrap modal http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/2.3.1/#/modal

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: If you changed the instances to `$uibModal` then it's impossible for the message to still show Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal", it cannot be the same issue...